# Change position of fields in a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a form in `MS-Access` with numerous fields and I want to move a field. I made a line of code for that but the field is not moving at all! This field takes numerical values.

```
Private Sub FC_Material_Weighed_g_Click()

  FC_Material_Weighed_g.Move FC_Material_Weighed_g.Left + 2000, FC_Material_Weighed_g.Top + 10000

End sub
```

I expect to move the field when we click on it.

Comment: It's unclear why your code is not doing anything.  Suggest you add `Option Explicit` to the form module's Declarations section if it's not there already.  Then prefix the control name with `Me.` like this ... `Me.FC_Material_Weighed_g.Move Me.FC_Material_Weighed_g.Left + 2000, Me.FC_Material_Weighed_g.Top + 10000` Finally run Debug->Compile from the VBA editor's main menu.  Does Access then complain about anything in your code?

Comment: Just curious ... why do you want to move the field each time it's clicked?

Comment: Not sure if you need to `.repaint` the form afterwards.